# Android error: Trying to install express on termux

Tags: android, express, npm, emulation, termux

It gives me this error when i run the command

```
npm install --save express
```

> Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, link
>   '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_cacache/tmp/e2710f83' ->
>   '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/59/ca/2e0f5017aa211536370255b2fbb493016a53ca7d335d077820223a58a86aa8771e6607b085e66f0dc28c2d783e58375a461ac72baa9eb974d71b24e41c03'

Comment: npm ERR! cb() never called!                             
npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

Answer (score 0):

Simply downgrade your npm version to npm 6 by running this command in node:

```
npm install -g npm@6
```

This will solve your issue because I have had this same issue and downgrading my npm version solved it.